# How do I make custom enchants

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

i can't find how to make custom enchants I'm clueless how to do it. I do want to know how to do it with no mods please help me I've been looking for like 5 months now

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create custom enchantments with command blocks.

Comment: I know I can make then with command blocks but how to make them with command blocks I don't know

Comment: Command blocks are limited to vanilla enchantments with optional non-vanilla modifier numbers (e.g. Efficiency 255)